# x64では32ビット整数と64ビット整数の演算はどちらが高速？

Tags: c++, c, cpu

特別困っているわけではないのですが、気になったので質問です。

int_fast16_t/int_fast32_tの実態がWindowsとLinuxで異なっているのですが、[x64](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/X64)では32ビット整数と64ビット整数の演算はどちらが高速なのでしょうか？
（Wikipediaの[注釈5](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/X64#cite_note-x86-compat-perf-5)にある資料がどういう比較なのか理解できていません。）

```
             | Linux(64)      | Windows(64)    | FreeBSD(64)
-------------+----------------+----------------+-------------
int_fast8_t  | signed char(8) | signed char(8) | int(32)
int_fast16_t | long(64)       | int(32)        | int(32)
int_fast32_t | long(64)       | int(32)        | int(32)
int_fast64_t | long(64)       | long long(64)  | long(64)
```

以下、int_fastN_tの実態を調査したプログラムです。

```cpp
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define PRINT_SAME_TYPE(d_type) \
    do { \
        ostringstream ostream; \
        ostream << #d_type << " = "; \
        if ( is_same<d_type, signed char>::value ) { \
            ostream << "signed char(" << CHAR_BIT << ")"; \
        } \
        else if ( is_same<d_type, short>::value ) { \
            ostream << "short(" << sizeof(short) * CHAR_BIT << ")"; \
        } \
        else if ( is_same<d_type, int>::value ) { \
            ostream << "int(" << sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT << ")"; \
        } \
        else if ( is_same<d_type, long>::value ) { \
            ostream << "long(" << sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT << ")"; \
        } \
        else if ( is_same<d_type, long long>::value ) { \
            ostream << "long long(" << sizeof(long long) * CHAR_BIT << ")"; \
        } \
        else { \
            ostream << "unknown"; \
        } \
        cout << ostream.str() << '\n'; \
    } while ( false )

int main()
{
    cout << "sizeof(char) = " << CHAR_BIT << '\n';
    cout << "sizeof(short) = " << sizeof(short) * CHAR_BIT << '\n';
    cout << "sizeof(int) = " << sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT << '\n';
    cout << "sizeof(long) = " << sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT << '\n';
    cout << "sizeof(long long) = " << sizeof(long long) * CHAR_BIT << '\n';
    cout << "sizeof(void *) = " << sizeof(void *) * CHAR_BIT << '\n';

    PRINT_SAME_TYPE(int_fast8_t);
    PRINT_SAME_TYPE(int_fast16_t);
    PRINT_SAME_TYPE(int_fast32_t);
    PRINT_SAME_TYPE(int_fast64_t);

    PRINT_SAME_TYPE(int_least8_t);
    PRINT_SAME_TYPE(int_least16_t);
    PRINT_SAME_TYPE(int_least32_t);
    PRINT_SAME_TYPE(int_least64_t);
}
```

Linux(64)での実行結果：

```
sizeof(char) = 8
sizeof(short) = 16
sizeof(int) = 32
sizeof(long) = 64
sizeof(long long) = 64
sizeof(void *) = 64
int_fast8_t = signed char(8)
int_fast16_t = long(64)
int_fast32_t = long(64)
int_fast64_t = long(64)
int_least8_t = signed char(8)
int_least16_t = short(16)
int_least32_t = int(32)
int_least64_t = long(64)
```

Windows(64)での実行結果：

```
sizeof(char) = 8
sizeof(short) = 16
sizeof(int) = 32
sizeof(long) = 32
sizeof(long long) = 64
sizeof(void *) = 64
int_fast8_t = signed char(8)
int_fast16_t = int(32)
int_fast32_t = int(32)
int_fast64_t = long long(64)
int_least8_t = signed char(8)
int_least16_t = short(16)
int_least32_t = int(32)
int_least64_t = long long(64)
```

16ビット以上あれば良い整数は長らくint型を使ってきましたが、64ビットマシン時代になってint型が「そのマシンでのワードの自然な大きさ」ではなくなってしまったようなので、これからはint型の代わりに何を使おうかなぁとふと思いまして。

---

Linuxと同じくLP64モデルを採用しているFreeBSDを調べてみると、LinuxともWindowsとも異なる結果でした。データモデルとは関係なさそうです。

FreeBSD(64)での実行結果：

```
sizeof(char) = 8
sizeof(short) = 16
sizeof(int) = 32
sizeof(long) = 64
sizeof(long long) = 64
sizeof(void *) = 64
int_fast8_t = int(32)
int_fast16_t = int(32)
int_fast32_t = int(32)
int_fast64_t = long(64)
int_least8_t = signed char(8)
int_least16_t = short(16)
int_least32_t = int(32)
int_least64_t = long(64)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

インテルの発行している[インテル®64アーキテクチャーおよびIA-32アーキテクチャー最適化リファレンス・マニュアルの９章 64 ビット・モードのコーディング・ガイドライン](http://www.intel.co.jp/content/dam/www/public/ijkk/jp/ja/documents/developer/248966-024JA.pdf#page=459)にいくつか説明がありますが

> ほとんどの命令では、デフォルトのオペランドサイズは 32 ビットである。
>
> **アセンブリー / コンパイラー・コーディング規則 65（影響 H、一般性 M）。** 64ビット・モードでは、64ビット・データや追加のレジスターへのアクセスに64 ビット版の命令が必要な場合を除き、32ビット版の命令を使うことでコードサイズを削減する。

とあるように、64ビット・モードにおいても32bitがほぼほぼデフォルトです。64bit演算を行うためには命令が１バイト長くなり、これによりキャッシュ効率が落ちます。

深い話は本書および本章を読まれるといいでしょう。

---

> なぜLinux（ClangもGCCも）はint_fast16～32_t=long(64)としたんでしょうね…？

残念ながらコンパイラーには選択権はありません。プラットフォームが決定したサイズに従うのみです。

ではどこで定められたものかというと、私も詳しくはありませんが、[Linux Standard Base](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base)の決定した[LSB 3.2](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml#LSB_3_2_0)に於いてAMD64アーキテクチャについては`int_fast16_t`=`int_fast32_t`=64bitと定められていました。

Comment: そうなると、これからも16ビット以上あれば良い整数にはint_fast16_t/int_fast32_tではなくintを使えば良いということになりますね。
しかし、なぜLinux（ClangもGCCも）はint_fast16～32_t=long(64)としたんでしょうね…？

Comment: @alpha さん、加筆しました。

Comment: Windowsで`int_fast16_t `が32ビットなのも、「64bit演算を行うためには命令が１バイト長くなり、これによりキャッシュ効率が落ちます。」と同じ理由で説明できますね。x86/x86-64の32/64ビットモードでは、16ビット演算も、やはり32ビット命令より1バイト多く必要になります（オペランドサイズプリフィックス）。