# なぜ int は short や byte より高速に処理できる場合があるのか

Tags: java, c, cpu

Java入門書を見ていたら、次のような記述がありました。

> 最近のコンピュータは多くのメモリを搭載しているため、これら4つの型を厳密に使い分ける必要があるケースはまれです。また、`short` や `byte` より `int` のほうが高速に処理できるコンピュータも多いので、 **整数を代入したい場合、通常は `int` 型** を使えば問題ありません。

何故shortやbyteなどの確保する記憶領域が少ないものの方が低速な処理になるという事が起こるのでしょうか？

何らかの最適化を行っているのでしょうが、直感とは反するので気になりました。

また、これはJavaのみの話ではなく他の言語でも同様なのでしょうか？(c言語など)

Comment: 一般に、int型はC言語処理系が対象とするCPUのレジスタ幅(ビット数)又はその半分に一致するように作られているため、演算効率が良い訳です。
これより少ないビット数はかえって手間がかかってしまうのですね。ただし、シリアルな通信においては転送対象の総ビット数が少ない方が効率的となります。

Answer (score 7):

実際の速度を決定づけているのはJavaやCなどの言語ではなく、演算を実行するプロセッサーです。プロセッサーは表面上は8bit / 16bit演算をサポートしている場合もありますが、それでも内部的には32bitなどより大きな値で演算を行った上で値を切り詰めている場合があります。32bit / 64bitプロセッサーが一般的となっている現在では、`int`などで演算を行うのが無難です。
その上で、大量の値を演算する場合は、不要なメモリアクセスを削減する目的で`char`や`short`などの適切な最小サイズを選択するべきですが、そうではない場合であれば、やはり`int`で十分です。

[x64では32ビット整数と64ビット整数の演算はどちらが高速？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/22346/4236)も参考にしてください。特にEgtraさんがコメントされていますが、x86 / x64プロセッサーでは16bit演算は8bit / 32bit演算に比べて少しだけ効率が悪いです。
またC言語においては`int_fast8_t`、`int_fast16_t`等、**8bit / 16bit演算を高速に行えるデータ型**という概念が存在します。（もっとも、x86 / x64 Linuxでは不適切で実際にはあまり高速ではないという欠点がありますが…。）

Comment: +1; `int_fastN_t`について少しだけ補足しておくと、「Nbit演算を高速に行えるデータ型」ではなく「少なくともNbit幅を持つうちで最も高速演算可能なデータ型」という定義です。（Nbit"保証"ではなくNbit”以上"という定義）

Comment: @sayuri 回答有難うございます。要するに、16bit演算、8bit演算を内部でサポートしているプロセッサーがあれば、
32bit演算で計算するための前処理(上位ビットに0を設定)と計算後に16bitや8bitにする後処理など余計な処理が産まれないため、byteやshortの方が高速になるという事ですか？

Comment: @sayuri リンク先のEgtraさんの「16ビット‌演算も、やはり32ビット命令より1バイト‌多く必要になります（オペランドサイズプリ‌フィックス）」が良く分かりません。
[オペランドサイズプリフィクスを調べると、](http://www.wdic.org/w/SCI/%E5%91%BD%E4%BB%A4%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9)「従来の16ビット命令の頭に「66」を置くことで、オペランドサイズが32ビットとなる」と書いてあってこれだけ見ると、
32ビット命令より1バイト多く必要になるように見えないからです。

Comment: @user25791 リンク先は16bitモードに関する説明ですので、32bit OSや64bit OSでは意味がありません。

Comment: @sayuri つまり、[このページ](http://masahir0y.blogspot.jp/2013/04/blog-post.html)の「64bitモードでは、アドレスサイズ64bit、オペランドサイズ32bitが基本。67を付けるとアドレスサイズが16bitになる。66を付けるとオペランドサイズが16bitになる。48を付けるとオペランドサイズが64bitになる。」というのが現在のパソコンの話でしょうか。ただ、これだと64ビット演算でも16ビット演算でも「オペランドサイズが"2バイト"増える」ためSayuriさんに提示して頂いたリンク先の話と合ってない気がするので間違っているような気もしますが、どこが間違っているのか分かりません。ご教示頂いてもよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @user25791 一般論を対象とした元質問から脱線しているように見受けられます。何を尋ねたいのか明確にするとともに、大きく話題が反れたのであれば新たなスレッドで質問し直してください。

Comment: @sayuri Syuriさんの回答で言及されていたEgtraさんの発言に関しての話なので関連事項として問題無いかと思っておりました。申し訳ありませんでした。後で、新しいスレッドで質問し直します。

Answer (score 1):

演算の面でいうと 32bit CPU は 32bit の演算のみができるものが多い（というかほとんど）で、つまり 16/8 bit の演算命令は無いわけです。 `short` や `byte` に対して演算を行う場合、結果を元の型つまり `short` や `byte` に収めるための命令が余計に生成されることになり性能が低下します。

(x86 は 16/8 bit の演算ができますし、数も多く出ていますが、互換性を維持するためにトランジスタ数が減らせなくてコストも高止まりしています。これが標準とは思わないほうが良い)

Answer (score 0):

（細かい話をすれば色々違うかもしれませんが以下は概念的な話として理解して下さい）
例えば、３２ビットコンピュータの場合、３２ビットのデータを扱えます。
３２ビットのデータを扱えるとは、８ビットのデータを４回に分けて扱う訳では無いということです。
つまり、メモリからレジスタにデータを読み出す場合(８ビットずつ４回にわけて読込されるのではなく)３２ビットが並列的に読み込まれます。
このような場合には、メモリから３２ビット毎の並びでデータを処理することが有利なわけです。
反面、同じように１バイト(８ビット)のデータをメモリから読み出す場合、バイトの位置（３２ビット単位でいうと４つの位置があります）によって調整する必要が生じます。
なので、その余分な操作の分速度に影響します。

Comment: 回答有難うございます。BLUEPIXYさんの回答は、他の方の回答とは違う話だと解釈してもいいのでしょうか？それとも、「プロセッサーに適したビット数の演算以外だとプレフィクスが付くことによって命令のサイズが増えるので効率が悪くなる」と同じ話だと捉えていいのでしょうか？

Comment: @user25791  具体的な命令セット以前の一般論だと思って下さい。

Comment: そうなのですね。「１バイト(８ビット)のデータをメモリから読み出す場合、バイトの位置（３２ビット単位でいうと４つの位置があります）によって調整する必要が生じます」これが良く分からないんです。例えばbyte型なら特定のメモリ番地からbyte分だけメモリを確保しているので、普通にメモリ番地を指定してそこから1バイトだけ読み出せば良いので、調整する必要が無い気がするのです。もし、1バイトだけ読み出すというのが無理で、そのメモリ番地から32ビット分読み出さないといけない場合でも、上位24ビットを無視すれば良いのでやはり調節する必要が無いように思えてしまいます。

Comment: @user25791  「メモ‌​リ番地を指定」というのがそもそも読み出し方法に依存していることに注意して下さい。

Comment: 「そのメモリ番地から32ビッ‌​ト分読み出さないといけない場合でも、上位‌​24ビットを無視すれば良いのでやはり調節‌​する必要が無い」 アライメント制約について調べてみるといいかもしれません。例えば[これ](http://www.ertl.jp/~takayuki/readings/info/no01.html) とか。